# Recursive & Asynchronous c++ Lambda

Tags: c++, ubuntu

### Environment:

- C++
- Ubuntu x64
- Asynchronous IO

### Code snippet:

```
spThreadPool->WaitForIO(EPOLLIN, fd, 
                        [spThreadPool, this, pBuf, uiTotalBytes, completion](int fd){
                              int iBytes = read(fd, pBuf, uiTotalBytes)
                              uiTotalByes -= iBytes;
                              pBuf += iBytes;
                              if(0 == uiTotalByes)
                                    completion(SUCCESS)
                              else
                                    spThreadPool->WaitForIO(EPOLLIN, fd, std::this_lambda())
                  })
```

### Flow of action:

- spThreadPool is executing asynchronous IO completion in an arbitrary thread
- Upon additional bytes availability (EPOLLIN) the lambda is called
- The lambda callback can return with partial read ( that is iBytes < uiTotalBytes )
- As long as the requested bytes were not fully read another Read req w/ the same lambda should be called
- **NOTE:** Since this is an async operation, the context is not preserved and stack variables are cleared

### Problem statement

Is there any way of referring the existing lambda functor with the new WaitForIO operation? eg. using the imaginary call std::this_lambda() ?

Comment: wouldn't it be simpler to return a state from the lambda? ie. 'finished' or number of bytes remaining and based on it simply continue or stop the read?

Comment: @NicolaeNatea yeah, I can do that, but I would like to keep the thread pool logic as simple as possible and would rather have external code implement the actual IO read/write, this way it is possible to abstract ThreaedPool better, eg. imagine integrating w Open SSL, and executing SSL_read / SSL_write

I have update the code spinet to better demonstrate the use-case

Comment: In this latest usecase it seems as if it would be simpler to simply add a while loop in the lambda, unless you want to somehow queue the request at the end of the pool. Anyway, I think the address of the first element, in this case 'spThreadPool', is the address of the lambda, but I don't think you could make use of that in this case. Anyway, there is I think nothing similar to std::this_lambda.

Comment: a loop wouldn't do since this is an AsyncIO, thus, rather than blocking on read for data to become avail, the thread tells the OS to notify it when data becomes avail and goes to do something else ( instead of blocking ), spThreadPool->WaitForIO is actually Queuing an AsyncIO... so the thread is not really waiting... and rather, executing some other code / ios